# How to setup my query correctly?

Tags: sql

Hey guys i have problems making a query. I have these Tables:

```
lm_Artikel:
Index, Artikelbezeichnung, Status, Bestand, 
Lieferant, Datum-Einlagerung, Lagerort, Typ 

lm_Schwellwert:
Typ, Schwellwert
```

The `Typ` value is the key. In `lm_Artikel` there are multiple artikel with the same `Typ`. For each `Typ` i have an `Schwellwert` in `lm_Schwellwert`. Now I want to select the Indexes of the articles where `Bestand` is lower than `Schwellwert`.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT `Index` 
  FROM lm_Artikel 
 WHERE Bestand < (SELECT Schwellwert FROM lm_Schwellwert)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want this:

```
SELECT A.`Index`
FROM lm_Artikel A
INNER JOIN lm_Schwellwert S
    ON A.Typ = S.Typ
WHERE A.Bestand < S.Schwellwert
```

Comment: thanks so much i will mark it as the correct answer when it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand it right...

1. calculate the number of all `Artikel` of same `Typ` from `lm_Artikel`
2. check if sum of `'Bestand'` of this `Typ` is less than `Schwellwert`
3. select all `Index` from `lm_Artikel` of determined `Typ`

You may try this:

```
SELECT `Index` 
FROM lm_Artikel m
JOIN
(
  SELECT s.`Typ` 
  FROM lm_Schwellwert s
  JOIN
  (
      SELECT `Typ`, SUM(`Bestand`) AS sumbestand
      FROM lm_Artikel
      GROUP BY `Typ`  
  ) t   
  ON s.`Typ`=t.`Typ`
  WHERE t.sumbestand<s.`Schwellwert`
)y
ON m.`Typ`=y.`Typ`
```

the `JOIN` inside determines which type's `'Bestand'` is less than it's corresponding 'Schwellwert'.

The wrapping `JOIN` is used to redetermine the `Index`s in the `lm_Artikel` table.

Comment: this probably simplifies to be the same thing as lamak'sanswer

Comment: I understand it different: I think there are several articles with the same type. so the sum of each stock has to be evaluated with the limit in `lm_Schwellwert` to determine the type. Once we have the type we can select the corresponding articles. But it's a lot of assumption in my interpretation.